# How to save file in vbscript with previous date

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to save excel file with previous date in vbscript.
Fill has been save but date format not like 5-Jun-2019.
Please help me..

MyDateFormat = Year(now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(now)-1, 2)
wbm.SaveAs "C:\report " & MyDateFormat & ".xlsx"

Expected Actual Result like:5-Jun-2019

Comment: `Wscript.Echo MyDateFormat` shows exactly `20190605` i.e. `yyyyMMdd` pattern; if you want another pattern containing an abbreviated month name (instead of month number) then calculate the `MyDateFormat` value using `MonthName(Month(DateAdd("d", -1, Now)), True)`.

Comment: Also note that  `Right("0" & Day(now)-1, 2)` returns `00` every 1st  day of any month…

Answer (score 0):

`date-1` gives yesterday "05.06.2019" in my case, this will not let you encounter `day = 00`, rest should be done by formatting